# onPageScrolled в ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Я попытался использовать `onPageScrolled`, но у меня возникла проблема на стадии вызова `.addOnPageChangeListener`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно здесь нужно использовать не `.addOnPageChangeListener`, а что-то иное, тогда подскажите что именно использовать.

Вот код из *MainActivity.java*:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /**
     * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
     */
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 6;

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
     * and next wizard steps.
     */
    private ViewPager2 viewPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    private FragmentStateAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager2 and a PagerAdapter.
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() { //Здесь и возникает ошибка
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Выбран " + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
            // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, select the previous step.
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }



    
    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents 6 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects, in
     * sequence.
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fa) {
            super(fa);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            return new fragment_screen_slide_page();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myViewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            Log.e("Selected_Page", String.valueOf(position));
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    });
```